# Sort core data using sort descriptors using variable held outside of core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, abaddressbook

My Question...

Is it possible to sort data using the sort descriptors in a fetchedResultsController by data that isnt stored in core data?

My situation...

I have a core data stack which includes a entity called 'Client'. One attribute of Client is addressBookID which contains the unique address book ID. I don't want to store names in my stack to avoid issues when names are updated etc...

Is it possible to fetch the results from core data, using the addressBookID get the names of the people and then sort them according to last name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben,

Core Data fetch requests return an array of objects. As such, you can sort a mutable copy of it based upon any criteria you dream up. Hence, the answer to your question is yes.

Andrew

Comment: is this still the case with  fetchedResultsController?

Comment: Ben, The NSFetchedResultsController is limited to predicates and sort descriptors that work on the fetched entity and its relations. Hence, the answer to your second question is no. Andrew P.S. If you are satisfied with my answer, please remember to check the little green arrow accepting the answer.)

Comment: Understood - Ill have to scrap the fetchedResultsController I think then! Thanks for your help.